# Swift: Multi item for loop to check input values in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop

I am trying to create a multi item for statement to test two values of an array. I have an array of type NSDate, with multiple dates saved from core data. I am aiming to take the dates from the array, and add them to a new array if the dates are on a unique day. I want to check the items in an array and if they have the same Day then not add them to a new array.

Currently I have been using calendar.components.Day to check if two dates have the same value, but it is not returning the correct answer:

```
func consecutiveDatesCheck(dateArray: [NSDate]) -> Int {

    // The incoming parameter dateArray is immutable, so first make it mutable
    var mutableArray = dateArray

    // Next, sort the incoming array
    mutableArray.sortInPlace({ $0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })

    var x = 0
    var numberOfConsecutiveDays = 1
    var streakArray = [Int]()
    var notSameDays = [NSDate]()

    // Cycle through the array, comparing the x and x + 1 elements
    while x + 1 < mutableArray.count {

        let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: mutableArray[x], toDate: mutableArray[x + 1], options: [])

        // If the difference between the dates is greater than 1, append the streak to streakArray and reset the counter
        if abs(components.day) = 0 {
            streakArray.append(numberOfConsecutiveDays)
            numberOfConsecutiveDays = 1
        }

            // If the difference between the days is exactly 1, add one to the current streak
        else if abs(components.day) == 1 {
            numberOfConsecutiveDays += 1
        }

        x += 1
    }

    // Append the final streak to streakArray
    streakArray.append(numberOfConsecutiveDays)
    print(streakArray)

    // Return the user's longest streak
    return streakArray.maxElement()!
}    /*
```

My current data in dateArray:

```
2016-08-20 06:38:23 +0000
2016-08-20 06:43:59 +0000
2016-08-20 06:49:19 +0000
2016-08-20 06:58:59 +0000
2016-08-20 07:05:44 +0000
2016-08-20 09:05:25 +0000
2016-09-02 12:05:55 +0000
2016-09-02 17:39:01 +0000
2016-09-03 13:37:31 +0000
2016-09-03 13:41:10 +0000
2016-09-03 13:59:36 +0000
2016-09-03 14:26:11 +0000
2016-09-03 14:48:57 +0000
2016-09-03 14:51:25 +0000
2016-09-03 15:06:56 +0000
2016-09-03 15:15:00 +0000
2016-09-04 13:53:48 +0000
2016-09-04 13:56:13 +0000
2016-09-04 14:16:29 +0000
2016-09-04 17:33:16 +0000
2016-09-05 16:53:32 +0000
2016-09-06 12:20:16 +0000
2016-09-06 15:19:14 +0000
2016-09-06 15:27:07 +0000
2016-09-06 15:30:48 +0000
2016-09-06 15:32:14 +0000
2016-09-06 15:39:34 +0000
2016-09-06 15:53:15 +0000
2016-09-06 16:08:45 +0000
2016-09-06 16:21:15 +0000
2016-09-06 17:41:09 +0000
2016-09-10 13:04:11 +0000
```

Comment: So you want to extract all the unique dates from an array of `NSDate`s, considering only day, month and year (ignoring hour, minute, second)?

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I want to do. I am then going to compare the dates to see how many days in a row the array contains from the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm not 100% clear on your requirements. I think what you want is the number of consecutive days, ending in the current day, for which you have measurements data. Updated my answer below.

```
func consecutiveDatesCheck(dateArray: [NSDate]) -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let uniqueDates = NSSet(array: dateArray.map { calendar.startOfDayForDate($0) }).sort {
        $0.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.timeIntervalSince1970
    } as! [NSDate]

    var lastDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
    var i = 0

    while i < uniqueDates.count && uniqueDates[i].compare(lastDate) == .OrderedSame {
        lastDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: lastDate, options: [])!
        i += 1
    }

    return i
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added the current data in my dateArray so I can explain what values are being returned when I add your code. When I run your code it returns: [6, 2, 8, 4, 1, 10, 1] for the data in steaks and 10 for the maxElement. Instead of the maxElement I want the streak from the current date if that makes sense?

Comment: And what's your expected output from your example above?

Comment: It would be 1, as there is a date on the 10th of september but then a gap until the 6th of september

Comment: So you want the *count of the last streak* in the array? If September 10 had not been there, you would expect it to return 10 (i.e. the streak of September 6)?

Comment: Sorry I should of explained better, I want the steaks of days a date is recorded. For example if there were dates recorded on 09/09, 09/10 and 09/11 I want it to return 3, if there were dates recorded on 09/08, 09/10 and 09/11 it would return 2, as there are two dates on consecutive days (09/08 is not consecutive so would break the streak). Does this make more sense?

Comment: A lot clearer. What's your expected output if the dates are `09/08, 09/09 and 09/11`?

Comment: That would be 1 assuming 09/11 is the current date, as it would be 1 day in a row from the current date

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!